# Add quotes and underscores to keys of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, key

I have an object with this shape :

```
{
IGG: "1007301297",
Date effet: "",
Statut deontologique: "B",
Version charte: "1",
N charte: "0",
Nom charte: "",
Statut charte: "A",
Date envoi charte: "",
Date 1ere relance: "",
Date 2eme relance: "",
Date 3eme relance: "",
Date de validation: "" 
}
```

but I want to replace all the spaces in keys by underscores and eventually add quotes like this :

```
{
"IGG": "1007301297",
"Date_effet": "",
"Statut_deontologique": "B",
"Version_charte": "1",
"N_charte": "0",
"Nom_charte": "",
"Statut_charte": "A",
"Date_envoi_charte": "",
"Date_1ere_relance": "",
"Date_2eme_relance": "",
"Date_3eme_relance": "",
"Date_de_validation": "" 
}
```

Is it possible ?

Explanation : In fact I parse a csv datas to JSON with npm package csv-parser, and I send the JSON back to the client. The JSON is valid in the backend route, but when I get it in client-side, I get the object like above

Comment: your object is not valid, how do you even define that?

Comment: In fact I parse a csv datas to JSON with npm package csv-parser, and I send the JSON back to the client. The JSON is valid in the backend route, but when I get it in client-side, I get the object like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
obj1 = { "Foo Bar": "Baz"};
obj2 = {};
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {obj2[key.replace(' ', '_')] = obj[key]});
```

You can do something like this!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you get the json data which you can parse. You can use map method to create new objects having the new keys like this

```js
var abc = {
  "IGG": "1007301297",
  "Date effet": "",
  "Statut deontologique": "B",
 "Version charte": "1",
  "N charte": "0",
  "Nom charte": "",
  "Statut charte": "A",
  "Date envoi charte": "",
  "Date 1ere relance": "",
  "Date 2eme relance": "",
  "Date 3eme relance": "",
  "Date de validation": "" 
}

const keyValues = Object.keys(abc).map(key => {
    const newKey = key.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
    return { [newKey]: abc[key] };
  });
  
console.log(keyValues)
```